# Cross-component communication via return key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enter

In my React.js to-do app, I'm trying to enable the return key to submit an item from my `TextInput` component to my `ToDoList` component. Right now the `TextInput.inputSubmit` method just console.logs the input value, but I'm wondering if I can have it trigger a prop (`enter={that.addToDo}`) inside of `ToDoList`. Or is there a better way?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26gptg8s/)

---

**Edit:** [improved JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26gptg8s/1/) (courtesy of knowbody)

---

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var todos = [{text: "walk dog"}, {text: "feed fish"}, {text: "world domination"}, {text: "integrate return key"}];

var TextInput = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {text: ''};
    },
    inputSubmit: function() {
        //I think I want to trigger ToDoList's addToDo method from here?
        console.log(this.refs.inputEl.getDOMNode().value);
        this.setState({text: ''});
    },
    handleChange: function(evt) {
        this.setState({text: evt.target.value});
    },
    handleKeyDown: function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13 ) {
            return this.inputSubmit();
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input value={this.state.text} ref="inputEl" onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}/>
        )
    }
});

var SubmitButton = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
           <button onClick={this.props.click}> Add </button>
        )
    }
});


var ToDo = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.click}>X</button>
                <span> - {this.props.text}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
});


var ToDoList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function (){
        return {
            todos: this.props.todos.splice(0)
        }
    },     
    deleteToDo: function(todo){
       this.state.todos.splice(this.state.todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
       this.setState({todos: this.state.todos});
    },
    addToDo: function(){
        this.state.todos.push({text: this.refs.textIn.refs.inputEl.getDOMNode().value});
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos
        });
        this.refs.textIn.setState({text: ''});
    },
    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
                    return (
                        <ToDo text={todo.text} click={that.deleteToDo.bind(null, todo)} />
                    )
                })}

                <br/>
                <TextInput ref="textIn" enter={that.addToDo} />
                <SubmitButton click={that.addToDo} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<ToDoList todos={todos} />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy but a quick fix will be to add:

`this.props.enter(this.refs.inputEl.getDOMNode().value);`

where your `console.log()` is. I will edit my answer with the full explanation once I'm on my laptop